# JMeter JAVA Request Plugin - Moving Objects and Data between plugins

Tags: java, jmeter

there is a way to move object (Customize) objects that i create with JAVA code between 2 diffrents plugins? because after running one plugins i JMETER all the Objects i created with JAVA code are gone.

For more Explanation: i have Plugin 1 that i Create an Object of Engineer for example and set data. than i want to move the Object of the Engineer to another Plugin 2 Request. But after the Plugin 1 Done all Object are gone.

Much Thanks,

Or Hasson

Answer (score 0):

I guess you’re speaking about the classname select box that changes  parameters depending on it?
This is not possible currently but you can duplicate element and modify it.

Or edit the jmx file as it’s xml to modify class name.

Comment: can you illustrate with screenshots your question ? not clear for me

Answer (score 0):

- Within the bounds of one [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

  - In 1st sampler

    ```
    Object myObject = new Object();
    context.getJMeterVariables().putObject("foo", myObject);
    ```
  - In 2nd sampler

    ```
    Object myObject = context.getJMeterVariables().getObject("foo");
    ```
- If you want to pass the values between different Thread Groups:

  - In 1st sampler

    ```
    Object myObject = new Object();
    context.getJMeterProperties().put("foo", myObject);
    ```
  - In 2nd sampler:

    ```
    Object myObject = context.getJMeterProperties().get("foo");
    ```

Where `context` is an instance of [JavaSamplerContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.html) class which you should have as a mandatory argument to your function

---

As an alternative to Java Request sampler you can consider using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which gives nearly the same performance and provides `vars` and `props` shorthands for [JMeter Variables and JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) correspondingly. In this case you won't have to recompile your code in case of changes and be able to embed in into .jmx script directly. Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information.